# Split Asp.Net Core Single Project App into multiple projects - The type conflicts with the imported type in xxx Using the type defined in xxx

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have been splitting my single project Asp.net Core app into different projects and I am seeing some strange errors and warnings and think maybe I have done it wrong. The main warning is that all through my files I have:

> The type 'VepoContext' in
> '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo/Vepo.Data/VepoContext.cs'
> conflicts with the imported type 'VepoContext' in 'Vepo.Data,
> Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type
> defined in
> '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo/Vepo.Data/VepoContext.cs'.
> [Vepo, Vepo]csharp(CS0436)

On most of my custom Classes.

I'm also getting:

> Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute'
> attribute [Vepo]

For which I have applied a few of the widely accepted Stack Overflow fixes, which have not worked.

This is my project structure. The project named "Vepo" is the Asp.net Core app and the other projects, Vepo.Data, Vepo.Domain, and Vepo.Common are all Class Library projects. I am wondering if I have placed my data, domain, and common projects inside the Asp.net Core project as it looks like that is the case in VS Code but not in Visual Studio:

In Visual Studio:
[image]

In VS Code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have placed your secondary projects inside the actual Vepo project. However, you also have the ones outside of the main project. Make sure to remove the ones inside the main since those are what are most likely causing you to get an error where two of the same types are loaded.

Comment: Thanks. The last time I deleted the ones that're inside the main project, it put a red circle cross on the outer projects of the same name and couldn't load them,  so I had to create the outer projects again. Then when I created them it created the inner ones again. So I am a bit scared to delete the inner ones again.

Comment: It may be because those folders are linked in Visual Studio or VS Code. Try copying the files as backups just in case.

Comment: You can just physically *move* the Vepo.Common/Vepo.Data/Vepo.Domain folders one folder up so they are next to the Vepo project folder. And then just adjust the paths in the solution file Vepo.sln so that Visual Studio (not Code) can find the projects again.